# Salesforce Javascript OnClick

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I'm trying to do something that should be very basic in SalseForce. I just need a button to run a small piece of javascript. It's throwing the following error at the moment "Invalid assignment left hand side error". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (  {!Contact.MailingPostalCode} =  'SC') {window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow'); }

if (  {!Contact.MailingPostalCode}  =  'FL')  {window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindow');  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `=` means assignment. `==` means comparison.

Comment: @Zach Colon, As a clarification, you would like Google to pop up if the Postal Code is NOT 'SC', correct?  And Yahoo if the Postal Cost is NOT 'FL'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `=` needs to be `==`.  You are assigning and what you want to do is compare.

EDIT: Also, your 'not', `!`, may need to be on the outside.  I'm not familiar with the SalesForce side.

EDIT 2: Try it this way:

```
if ({!Contact.MailingPostalCode} == 'SC') {
    window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow');
}
if ({!Contact.MailingPostalCode} == 'FL') {
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindow');
}
```

TESTING:

```
if ({!Contact.MailingPostalCode} == 'SC') {
    window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow');
}
else if ({!Contact.MailingPostalCode} == 'FL') {
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindow');
}
else {
    alert({!Contact.MailingPostalCode});
}
```

EDIT 3:
For completeness, @Zach Colon's code is:

```
if ('{!Contact.MailingState}' == 'SC') {
    window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow');
}
if ('{!Contact.MailingState}' == 'FL') {
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindow');
}
```

Comment: Tried that too. Checked again just now. When I use '==' the button doesn't do anything period. No error, nothing.

Comment: @ZachColon, I gave some sample code.  Try that.  I think the '!' may have also been throwing things off.

Comment: It's a salesforce variable. Doesn't mean not in this example.

Comment: Ok, good clarification.  The answers my comment under your original post.

Comment: @ZachColon, try the code I put under TESTING: and see what you get.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Couldn't post my own answer b/c I have less than 10 reputation points. I made a stupid mistake and grabbed the wrong variable. 

{!Contact.MailingPostalCode} is a zip code not a state. Should have been {!Contact.MailingState}.

Also, still throws an error using "==". Works using "=".  For some reason it's treating "SC" as a variable not a string using "=="

Comment: @ZachColon, That is very odd.  Well, glad you figured it out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the quotes for your SF variable **'**{!Contact.MailingPostalCode}**'**:

```js
if ('{!Contact.MailingPostalCode}' == 'SC') {
    window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow'); 
}

if ('{!Contact.MailingPostalCode}' == 'FL'){
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindow'); 
}
```